# Tensorflow 1 vs Tensorflow 2 Keras Inference Speed Differ by 2+ times

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to figure out the reason behind speed different from two different models.

1. an LSTM RNN model built using tensorflow 1.x:

> ```
>     self.input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
>         tf.int32, shape=[self.config.batch_size, self.config.num_steps], name='Input')
>     self.labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
>         tf.int32, shape=[self.config.batch_size, self.config.num_steps], name='Target')
>     embedding = tf.get_variable(
>         'Embedding', initializer = self.embedding_matrix, trainable = False)
>     inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.input_placeholder)
>     inputs = [tf.squeeze(x, axis = 1) for x in tf.split(inputs, self.config.num_steps, axis = 1)]
>     self.initial_state = tf.zeros([self.config.batch_size, self.config.hidden_size])
>     lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.config.hidden_size)
>     outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
>         lstm_cell, inputs, dtype = tf.float32, 
>         sequence_length = [self.config.num_steps]*self.config.batch_size)
>     with tf.variable_scope('Projection'):
>         proj_U = tf.get_variable('Matrix', [self.config.hidden_size, self.config.vocab_size])
>         proj_b = tf.get_variable('Bias', [self.config.vocab_size])
>         outputs = [tf.matmul(o, proj_U) + proj_b for o in rnn_outputs]
> ```

2. the same model (at least from my understanding) built using tensorflow 2.0 keras:

> ```
> def setup_model():
>     model = Sequential()
>     model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
>                         output_dim=embedding_dim,
>                         weights=[embedding_matrix],
>                         input_length=4,
>                         trainable=False))
>     model.add(LSTM(config.hidden_size, activation="tanh"))
>     model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax"))
>     return model
> ```

The architecture is:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 4, 100)            55400     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 554)               55954     
=================================================================
Total params: 191,754
Trainable params: 136,354
Non-trainable params: 55,400
_________________________________________________________________
```

I was expecting similar inference runtime but the one built with tensorflow 1.x is much much faster. I was trying to convert tensorflow 1.x model to tensorflow 2 using only native tensorlow functions, but I have trouble converting due to the big change in tensorflow from 1.x to 2, and I was only able to create it using tf.keras.

In terms of speed, since I'm using both for generating text sequences + getting word probabilities, so I don't have a single inference time difference (I can't modify existing API from tensorflow 1.x model to get this). But in general, I'm seeing at least 2x difference in time from my use cases.

What can be the **possible** reasons behind this difference of inference speed? I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: can we see your code? in the mean time, have you used `tf.function`?

Comment: @JoelB I will update the code tmr. I have searched about tf.function, but no, I haven't tried it yet, I'm not 100% sure how to apply that to keras model.

Comment: @JoelB I have updated the code. I didn't build the tensorflow 1.x model so I was having trouble converting it using tensorflow graph using tensorflow 2.x, especially due to the problem with variable scopes.